# C# localization, db

Tags: c#, localization

I'm developing a WPF app which loads data from a database. I want to support localization so I am thinking about the right way how to localize text from database.

Is it good idea to store translations for each language or store only resource key and search the resource for given language?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store only resource key in the DB and get the localised value inside the app. One advantage is that if you later need to support additional languages, only your resource file gets modified, you won't need to add new values to your DB. Also if it's in your DB you need to have customised queries to get the correct string, if you only store the key in the DB, your app should work with new languages without modifying your DB. My two cents.